# Hat dir der Film gefallen? Why "der Film" and not "den Film"?

Tags: grammatical-case, accusative

I came across this exercise and I don't understand why is it not "hat dir den Film gefallen?" since it should be accusative asking the question "what did you like". Am I wrong and why?

Comment: Whoever is downvoting and voting to close every second question, could you please stop? This seems in no way constructive. What makes it worse is that the close reason is usually not appropriate. In this case, it's very easy to understand what OP is asking. With a few seconds of searching, this question could have been found: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/36957/how-should-i-understand-constructions-using-this-verb-gefallen/36960#36960

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I understand constructions using this verb: »gefallen?«](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/36957/how-should-i-understand-constructions-using-this-verb-gefallen)

Comment: Hi thanks, but that's is not what I asked...I didn't asked for "dir" I know how to use that. I asked why is it "der Film" and not "den Film". I've searched and I couldn't find an explication for that. I've edited my question to make it more clear.

Comment: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/52562/why-dem-computer-and-not-der-computer/52599#52599 is a similar question about a different verb (so I don't think the question is a duplicate).

Comment: It should NOT be Akkusativ! It should be Nominativ bc it's the do-er: The film pleases you. It's not that you like the film!

Comment: @Karen: Since the answer to your question is all about "dative is the way to go" (Wem hat der Film gefallen?) - do you find your answer in the second question example by David Vogt?

Comment: As mentioned in a previous comment, "gefallen" is rather equivalent to "to please". The better translation for "to like" is "mögen". Words that follow the pattern of "gefallen" also exist in other languages. In Spanish it's "gustar" and in French, I think, "plaire".

Comment: @Karen If you'd really understand the "Dir" as you claimed, you should also realise that this is dative and therfore the/an object of the sentence, so the logical conclusion is, that "der Film" is the subject. This is clearly explained in the (second) link given by David Vogt, and I'm voting to close this question as duplicate.

Answer (score 8):

> Der Film hat dir gefallen.

*Der Film* is subject. (nominative)

Now make it a question:

> Hat dir der Film gefallen?

English questions don't work in regard of finding the right case in German. The question

> (Wer oder) was hat dir gefallen?

would indicate nominative and its equivalent in English would be something like

> What was to your liking.

The questions

- wer oder was (nom.)
- wessen (gen.)
- wem (dat.)
- wen (acc.)

work only for native speakers to find the right case and only in German.

Comment: The questions only work if you already know what case to use, so it's kind of useless.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the Englich verb *"to like"* and the German verb *"gefallen"* work in different ways:

> I like you.
>   Du gefällst mir.

There is one item that is attracting. I call it the *attractor.* The other item is attracted by the attractor, I call it the *fan.*

In the English version you find the fan in the active position of the subject. The fan is doing something (he *likes*) and the attractor is in the passive position of an object.

In German it's the other way round: The attractor is actively doing something: *er gefällt*, and the fan is just the passive object that receives the attractors charisma. So in German the attractor has to be the subject in the sentence (and therefore must be used in nominative case) while the fan is the verb's object (which has to be in dative case, because *gefallen* wants to have it's object in dative case).

It is rare, but *gefällt* also can be used without it's object:

> Sie gefällt.
>   She is liked.

In German this is a sentence in active mode, in English you can't build this sentence in active mode, you have to use passive mode.

More often you find this usage together with a negation:

> [Wenn die Geschenke nicht gefallen](https://www.smarticular.net/geschenk-gefaellt-nicht-was-tun/) - When the presents are not liked
>   [Hochzeitsfotos gefallen nicht. Was tun?](https://www.vibo.photography/hochzeitsfotos-gefallen-nicht/) What to do when wedding pictures are not liked?

On the other hand in English you can have a button on a website that just says *"like"* and you click it to show the world, that **you** like a certain posting. This doesn't work in German. Because you want to signal that **you** like this posting, and because in German the fan is not the active subject but the passive receiver of the attractors attractiveness, you have to add the first person's personal pronoun in dative case, and then you get: *gefällt mir*:

> Like
>    Gefällt mir

Answer (score 1):

While in abstract level we have a subject, i. e. a person with an opinion concerning some object, in German the respective cases depend only on the specific verb used, overshadowing this generic situation:

- Wie hat Dir (dative) der Film (nominative) gefallen?
- Was hältst Du (nominative) von dem Film (dative)?
- Magst Du (nominative) den Film (accusative)?
- Wie findest Du (nominative) den Film (accusative)?

So *gefallen* is somewhat non-standard by requiring dative for the subject.